# Как сделать так чтобы сообщения отправляемые ботом в чат не слипались друг с другом ? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Как сделать так чтобы сообщения отправляемые ботом в чат и не слипались друг с другом ? Discord.py
Я хочу чтобы каждое новое сообщение было как 1 с именем бота так сказать
[image: Я хочу чтобы каждое новое сообщение было как 1 с именем бота так сказать]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это никак нельзя сделать, так как это заложено самим discord. И это есть не только в discord. Если сообщения отправляются через короткий промежуток времени, то они `'слипаются'`. Можете почитать о рейт [лимитах discord](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits)

Comment: Спасибо большое